# XQuery Node By Value Then Its Sibling

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery, sql-server-2016, sqlxml

```
<a>
    <b>111</b>
    <c>AAA</c>
    <b>222</b>
    <c>BBB</c>
    <b>333</b>
    <c>CCC</c>
</a>
```

The above value is found in the an XML typed column in SQL Server.

I want to find the value for node  located after node  with the value of "111". Can this be done using XQuery?

So far I have:

```
SELECT X.Y.value('('b[.="111"])[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS 'MyColumn'
FROM DBTable
CROSS APPLY DocXml.nodes('/a') AS X(Y);
```

This gets me the first node but I haven't been able to get the sibling.

Comment: Don't know about SQL Server, but "normally" you would get `AAA` by using `//b[.="111"]/following-sibling::c[1]/.`

Comment: @JackFleeting Unfortunately SQL Server does not support sibling axes

Comment: @Charlieface That is indeed unfortunate... Well, live and learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL Server does not support sibling axes, which would have made this simpler.

Instead, you need to do the following

- Save the `b` node into a variable using `let`
- Take all nodes of the root by using `*`, filter by checking each one to see if it follows `b`, return the first one.
- Note that you should use `text()` to get the inner text of a node, rather than relying on implicit conversion.

```sql
SELECT
  x1.a.value('let $b := b[text() = "111"][1] return (*[. >> $b]/text())[1]','varchar(100)')
FROM DBTable t
CROSS APPLY t.DocXml.nodes('/a') x1(a);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=af127bca2b38036bc15c055e8aacb113)

Comment: That solved my issue, thanks.